# Scrolling down with PhantomJS until end of page

Tags: javascript, scroll, phantomjs

As the title says, I am trying to scroll down a webpage using PhantomJS. This is as far as I have:

```
var i = 0;
page.open(address, function () {

   window.setInterval(function() {

      i++;
      if(i<5) {
         page.evaluate(function() {
            window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
         });
      }
      else { // Timeout
         fs.write(dir, page.content, 'w');
         phantom.exit();
      }

   }, 1000); // Number of milliseconds to wait between scrolls  
});
```

This code works, and write in a file the content of a webpage using scroll after 5 second, so depends of how long is the webpage, it download all of it or just half, quarter...

Well, my problem is to code the condition of the end of the page. I tried to do an `if (window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight)` inside `page.evaluate` but it doesn't work. I also tried to compare the contents between iterations and I think that works but it is not a good solution:

```
window.setInterval(function() {

   a = page.content;
   if (a == b) {
      console.log('END');
   } else {
      console.log('NO END');
   }

      ...
      fs.write(dir, page.content, 'w');
      phantom.exit();
   }

   b = page.content;
   a = b;

}, 1000); // Number of milliseconds to wait between scrolls
```

I am kind of noob in this matter so I would appreciate some advice. Any ideas?

Comment: Usually there is some kind of element on the page that either vanishes or appears when there are no more items to load. Is this the case for your page?

Comment: Why do you think comparing the page content to see if there is a change is not a good solution? I think it's perfectly fine. You could do this a little lighter by checking how many items there are on the page, but it's essentially the same thing.

Comment: Comparing page content works as I said but if the page content changes when it's completely loaded It will not. I just think there are better solutions. For example: if you can't scroll down it is because you are already in the bottom.